# iTunes Image in Project properties

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In the new MonoDevelop 2.8 and MonoTouch 5, there is an option to put a 512x512 image in project properties, see below. Given that you need to provide that when submitting an app via the iTunes Connect site, why is it needed here?

[image: Why needed?]